# Restart functions with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT*

In my word game I have added a restart button. The problem with it at the moment is that when I press it, it goes back to the start screen, like it should. But when the start button is clicked for the second time it brings back the previous game that has already been played. I have now put all my code into separate functions so that I can run them again for a new game. The problem is I don't know how to clear the last game in order to start it again. How would I restart all the functions when this button is clicked?

I have the functions..

```
createGrid()
startplay()
restartplay()
keyPress()
backGroundSound()
dragEvent()
nextQuestion()
closeMessage()
replaySound()
backGroundImage()
```

and I run them all in a document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

backGroundSound();
createGrid();
keyPress();
backGroundImage();
playBackGroundSound();
dragEvent();

$('.next-question').on('click', function () {
    nextQuestion();
});
$('.close-message').one("click", function () {
    closeMessage();
});
$(".replay-sound").click(function () {
    replaySound();
});
//Click event to start the game
$(".start-btn-wrapper").click(function () {
    startplay();
});
//Click event to restart the game
$(".restart-btn").click(function () {
    restartplay();
});
```

When the restart button is clicked I want it to flush the functions, then when the start button is clicked again, start a new game for the user. How would I do this without just refreshing the page?

I want to clear functions when the restart-button is clicked and then start them again when the start button is clicK.

This fiddle only has the script in: http://jsfiddle.net/V4SYZ/

Comment: What has this to do with java? Please tag your questions appropriate.

Comment: You tagged this question with Java; [Java and JavaScript are not the same thing](http://javascript.crockford.com/javascript.html).

Comment: What does `restartplay()` do? Does it already run some of those other functions? If the game and those functions were designed the way I would do it you would just have to run all of the functions you run at the start in the `$.ready()` event. If that is the case, I would keep things DRY by also abstracting that series of calls into a `newGame()` function and calling that in `$.ready()` and the `.restart-btn` click handler. My guess is that `restartplay()` already does something like this?

Comment: No it just adds and removes the necessary classes @Useless Code

Comment: I've noticed some other problems in your code, the statement `if (populationNumber >= 6) {` will always evaluate to `false`, `populationNumber` is an array which in this sort of comparison will  be coerced to the integer `1`. 1 will always be smaller than 6, thus that statement always returns false. You probably meant `if (populationNumber.length >= 6) {` which means "if there are six or more items in the `populationNumber` array". There is a similar problem with an `if` statement involving `completionNumber` too.

Comment: It appears that you are pretty new to JavaScript, the two books I always recommend for anyone learning JS are **Object-Oriented JavaScript: Create scalable, reusable high-quality JavaScript applications and libraries** by _Stoyan Stefanov_ and **JavaScript: The Good Parts** by _Douglas Crockford_. Both are excellent books that will teach you about the JavaScript language and how to better use it. I would also recommend getting to know [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) (after you read JavaScript: The Good Parts, which explains Mr. Crokford's reasoning for most of the policies JSLint enforces).

Comment: The thing is that population number and completion number are one number arrays. What I am trying to say is that if population number is greater than the number 6 (ie. 10) then make it 6 anyway. @UselessCode

Comment: If they will always be an one-item array, you are adding needless overhead, it would be better to just use a number. At any rate, if there is a reason to keep it an array then what you would want to do is `if (populationNumber[0] >= 6) {` which will compare the first (and only) item in the array to 6. Likewise you would then need to set the first item inside the body of the if `populationNumber[0] = 6` or `populationNumber = [6]`; the first way which replaces the existing item is [much faster](http://jsperf.com/so13561705). The second way creates an entirely new array and may be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just need to clean out whatever data-structure you were storing the data from the last game in. For example if it was in an array reset it to an empty array with `data = []` or if in an object an empty object `data = {}`, etc. It is hard to be more specific without knowing more about the structure of the code and how it works.

**Edit**

Looking at the code you posted in that fiddle, right before you call all those functions in the `$.ready()` event you initialize a bunch of variables to empty arrays; I haven't looked to closely at the code but you probably need to do that again to get your new game started.

As I previously suggested, I would move that code into a new function:

```
Function newGame() {
    randomWord = [];
    listOfWords = [];
    attemptNumber = [];
    completionNumber = [];
    populationNumber = [];
    gridSize = [];

    backGroundSound();
    createGrid();
    keyPress();
    backGroundImage();
    playBackGroundSound();
    dragEvent();
}
```

And then call the `newGame()` function in the `$.ready()` handler and the click handler for `.restart-btn`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    newGame();

    $('.next-question').on('click', function () {
            nextQuestion();
    });
    $('.close-message').one("click", function () {
            closeMessage();
    });
    $(".replay-sound").click(function () {
            replaySound();
    });
    //Click event to start the game
    $(".start-btn-wrapper").click(function () {
            startplay();
    });

    //Click event to restart the game
    $(".restart-btn").click(function () {
            newGame();
            restartplay();
    });     

});
```

Comment: I can send a fiddle with just the jquery in @Useless Code

Comment: Thanks, I am almost there. The problem now is that it starts the function again but the old one is still there. How do I clear the old one? @Useless Code

Comment: It's getting late here, I'll try to take another look at it tomorrow. I've not looked at any of the code that manipulates the DOM but I'm guessing you need to reset the values in some DOM nodes so you see the reset values when you start a new game.

Comment: How would I do that? @Useless Code

Comment: I have tried this way already and it still brings back the old game as well as the new one. Any ideas how I would clear the old one? @Useless Code

Answer (score 0):

Could always just do a non-cached reload, like so:

`window.location.reload(true);`

That tells the browser to reload the page and explicitly **not** to use whatever it has in memory (basically, the same as a `Cntrl+F5` on a Windows machine). This assumes you don't need to retain anything in the current "session," though.

Comment: I need something a lot smoother @Tieson T

Comment: Something that doesn't just refresh the page. When the restart button is pressed I have animations that happen as it goes back to the start screen. When you reload this will not happen. I need clear the functions when the restart button is pressed and then restart the functions when the start button is pressed @Tieson T

Comment: So you want those first 6 or so methods to be called again?

Comment: No I want createGrid(), backgroundImage(), nextquestion(), closeMessage() and replaySound() @Tieson T